# Remove cache after service call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching

So I have service with two methods. I am using built-in cache support for $resource. What i want to achieve is when i make some service call from controller to refresh cache. I was trying some example with $cacheResource but no success. Below is my code

**Service**

```
angular.module('module').factory('Service1',['$resource',
   function ($resource){
     return $resource('..api/latest/myservice', {}, {

       takeSomething: {
         method: 'GET',
         url: '..api/latest/myservice/takesomething',
        cache: true
       },

       putSomething: {
         method: 'GET',
         url: '..api/latest/myservice/putsomething',
         cache: true
       }

      }
}]
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('module').factory('MyController',['$scope','Service1',
     function($scope, service1) {
       ....

     $scope.update = function() {
       service1.putSomething({
       ......
       refresh cache for takeSomething method in service or for all methods
     });
     }

}
```

So when i call this function update from controller i want to refresh cache for takeSomething methods or for all methods.

Comment: `cache: false` ? Do you want cache value to be dynamic ? And you want it to be different for each api call ?

Comment: Well i want to be cache: true, cause I am using that for other calls from controller. But only with this call from controller i want to refresh cache.

Comment: Storing `true/false` values in global variable in `service scope` and using another method in `service` to update that global variable ? Sounds good ?

Comment: hm... then what is best approach for this?

Comment: I had a similar problem with fetching some Jsons from an Apache2 server and I always had issues with getting fresh jsons. I solved it attaching a currentTime to the $http GET request.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the default `$http` cache by using `$cacheFactory`; this will have a `remove` method to do what you want.

You need to inject `$cacheFactory` wherever you plan to use it, in your `$scope.update` or you could move it to your service.

```
var $httpDefaultCache = $cacheFactory.get('$http');

$httpDefaultCache.remove('..api/latest/myservice/takesomething');
```